Unknown type name ‘Node’ in the parser file. (Yacc program)
I've been working on a Yacc program (parser.y) to develop a small compiler that handles arithmetic operations. I'm using Yacc (Bison) and Lex tools to generate the parser and lexical analyzer, respectively. However, when I compile the program, I encounter this error! The error message says, "unknown type name 'Node'" despite having declared it in the declaration section. I've tried various solutions, but none have resolved the issue. My parser.y file code is given below. (By the way please consider that I am new to this lex and yacc tech ) I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this error. Thank you!
%{

#include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char* type;              // Type of the node (e.g., "E", "T", "F", "+", "NUMBER", "ID")
    int num_children;        // Number of child nodes
    struct Node** children;  // Array of pointers to child nodes
}Node;
#include "lex.yy.c"




void yyerror (char *s);
int yylex();

int symbols[52];// 26 for lowercase letters, 26 for uppercase letters
// Function prototypes for symbol table operations
int symbolVal(char symbol);
void updateSymbolVal(char symbol, int val);



Node* createNode(char* type, int num_children, ...);
Node* createLeafNode(void* data);
void printParseTree(Node* node, int level);
Node* rootNode = NULL;


%}

/* Yacc definitions */

%token  PRINTFF ADD MULTIPLY DIVIDE SUBTRACT UNARY LPAREN RPAREN
%union {
    int num;        // For NUMBER token
    char* id;       // For ID token
    Node* node;     // For non-terminal nodes in the parse tree
}       

%token <num> NUMBER
%token <id> ID
%type <node> E T F E_prime T_prime

%start E
%%

    E   :   T E_prime           {$$ = createNode("E", 2, $1, $2);}
        |   PRINTFF E           {$$ = createNode("PRINTFF", 1, $2);}
        ;
    
    E_prime :   ADD T E_prime           {$$ = createNode("+", 2, $2, $3);}
        |   /* Empty production for E' */   { $$ = NULL;}
        ;
        
    T   :   F T_prime           {$$ = createNode("T", 2, $1, $2);}
        ;
    
    T_prime :   MULTIPLY F T_prime      {$$ = createNode("*", 2, $2, $3);}
        |   /* Empty production for T' */   { $$ = NULL;}
        ;
    
    F   :   LPAREN E RPAREN         {$$ = createNode("()", 1, $2);}
        |   ID              {$$ = createNode("ID", 1, createLeafNode($1));}
        |   NUMBER              {
                                int* num = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
                                *num = $1;
                                $$ = createNode("NUMBER", 1, createLeafNode(num));
                            }

        ;
            



%%                     /* C code */


Node* createNode(char* type, int num_children, ...) {
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->type = strdup(type);
    node->num_children = num_children;
    node->children = (Node**)malloc(num_children * sizeof(Node*));

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num_children);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_children; i++) {
        node->children[i] = va_arg(args, Node*);
    }
    va_end(args);

    return node;
}

Node* createLeafNode(void* data) {
    Node* leaf = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    leaf->type = (char*)data;
    leaf->num_children = 0;
    leaf->children = NULL;
    return leaf;
}
void printParseTree(Node* node, int level) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        printf("  ");
    }
    printf("%s\n", node->type);

    for (int i = 0; i < node->num_children; i++) {
        printParseTree(node->children[i], level + 1);
    }
}
int computeSymbolIndex(char token)
{
    int idx = -1;
    if(islower(token)) {
        idx = token - 'a' + 26;
    } else if(isupper(token)) {
        idx = token - 'A';
    }
    return idx;
} 

/* returns the value of a given symbol */
int symbolVal(char symbol)
{
    int bucket = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    return symbols[bucket];
}

/* updates the value of a given symbol */
void updateSymbolVal(char symbol, int val)
{
    int bucket = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    symbols[bucket] = val;
}

int main (void) {
    /* init symbol table */
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
        symbols[i] = 0;
    }

    yyparse ( );
    
    if (rootNode != NULL) {
        printf("Parse Tree:\n");
        printParseTree(rootNode, 0);
    }
        
        return 0;
}

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);} 

In case if you need my lex program. Here it is .
/* Auxillary declarations starts here */
%{
    #include "y.tab.h"
    void yyerror (char *s);
    int yylex();
    
         int countn=0;       /* for keeping track of the line number */
%}

/* Regular expressions */
%option yylineno

digit [0-9]
letter [A-Za-z]
id     {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
unary "++"|"--"

/* Translation rules */
%%


"printf"                    {  return PRINTFF; }
[-]?{digit}+                { yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
{letter}    { yylval.id = (char*)malloc(2); strncpy(yylval.id, yytext, 1); yylval.id[1] = '\0'; return ID; }
{unary}                     {  return UNARY; }
"+"                         {  return ADD; }
"-"                         {  return SUBTRACT; }
"/"                         {  return DIVIDE; }
"*"                         {  return MULTIPLY; }
"("                         { return LPAREN;}
")"                         { return RPAREN;}
\/\/.*                      { ; }                   /* Handle the single line comments */
\/\*(.*\n)*.*\*\/           { ; }                   /* Handle the multi line comments*/
[ \t]*                      { ; }
[\n]                        { countn++; }
.                           { ECHO; yyerror ("unexpected character"); }         /* Handles all other symbols */

%%

/* Auxiliary functions */
int yywrap() {
    return 1;  // Always indicate end of input
}



I have tried several ways to declare this struct but nothing worked.

As far as I remember, the things in normal code blocks aren't put into the generated header file. You probably need to add a qualifier to the block: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/_0025code-Summary.html. provides seems appropriate.
